# Problem in Spring enabled controller page rendering in jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When i do this.

```
@RequestMapping("/folder/{name}.jsp")
public ModelAndView catchAll(@PathVariable String viewName) {
    return new ModelAndView("legacy/" + viewName);
}
```

it give an error on the browser that

> legacy/123.jsp is not available

How can I resolve this issue

if i have a list of id,

i want that the browser show like this /legacy/1 /legacy/2  etc   so for that how can i program in spring

Comment: Think about the context root you're going back to.  What's the full path to that resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling Spring to render a jsp page that doesn't exist. If the name of your jsp is "legacy.jsp", that's the view you render, and you're just passing a different object to the view based on the parameter. If you want `legacy/123` to take you to "legacy.jsp" which will show a Legacy object with the id of 123, then you do it like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/legacy/{id}")
public ModelAndView catchAll(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
  Legacy legacy = // Get the object from your database using the id
  return new ModelAndView("legacy", "legacy", legacy); // insert the legacy object into your view, it will be accessed by the name "legacy"
}
```

So this way, you enter the url "/legacy/123" in your browser (or click a link to it) and it just renders the `legacy.jsp` with the object you fetched using the id `123`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put an 123.jsp in the `legacy` subdirectory of the directory where you put your JSPs.

But I guess that is not what you want: I asssume you want to build somekind of forwarding. In this case you have to return an redirect view.

```
@RequestMapping("/folder/{name}.jsp")
public ModelAndView catchAll(@PathVariable String viewName) {
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("legacy/" + viewName + ".jsp"));
}
```

Comment: yea means if i have a list so the acording to id the legacy/{id} is adjusted

Comment: Sorry i did not understand your comment? Is it a question, more details of your question, or the confirmation that it works?

Comment: there is 1 jsp page say view.jsp, so via spring it is rendered as view.htm, ok that is fine, but now i want to pass a list to it, and according to the given id from the list, the view.htm is change to view.htm/{id} but if i have 100 data, then do i need 100 jsp pages ?? how can i resolve this via spring

Comment: Let me summarize to make sure that i get it right: you have a request containing a number in its url (/folder/1.jsp, folder/2.jsp ...) and you want to pass that number to your jsp, (and of course you want only to have 1 controller method and one jsp) -- is this correct?